# Rooting Samsung Galaxy Young 2 (SM-G130HN)

Tags: rooting, samsung

I am having issues in rooting the Samsung Galaxy Young 2 (SM-G130HN).

I did search online and found a root file named `G130HNXXU0ANH2_ROOT.tar`. The method described in various android forums did not work : everything seems fine, but when I restart my phone and check with SuperSU, I am not root.

[image: Root Samsung results]

and I suspect the reason is that my phone has a different baseband number. Mine is `G130HNXXU0APA2`. Considering the name of the root file name, it might only work on baseband number `G130HNXXU0ANH2`.

I've checked on this list [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device/1185?newreg=507db9fa846b4c8db5333387b99f83b6) and I'm afraid my phone is too old (for this sh**)...

Am I right in thinking that the reason of the fail could be the band base number? Is it possible to change this number so the file I have would fit?

Another solution could be having the right root file corresponding to my baseband number but I can't find it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52069/discussion-between-andy-yan-and-bebs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of rooting is to use a custom recovery to install a [SuperSU zip](http://download.chainfire.eu/supersu), which not only contains the SuperSU app itself, but also proper binaries and tools. Luckily, this unloved device still has a custom recovery available in this [XDA-Developers thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/android/hello-sm-g130-users-d-t3132743).

Install the CWM package via Odin, then install SuperSU from it. Don't bother with the build.prop and custom ROM mess, those are for another purpose.

---

*I was helped by @Andy's answer and I wanted to add more details about the rooting of the Samsung Galaxy Young 2 (SM-G130HN).  <sub>Bebs</sub>*

### Root

After the first steps described in the question, I had to try another rooting method. I found one in this post [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device), and the ont that worked is

> [Kingoapp](http://www.kingoapp.com)

I had to download it from my hpone because my PC navigator detected a troyan. It indeed worked with one clic.

### CWM

At this moment, I still could not use SuperSU --the one dowloaded from Google Play--, my phone was seen as rooted, but there were a problem with SuperSU.

I learned from [this page](https://forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/android/hello-sm-g130-users-d-t3132743) I could manually install another SuperSU package but first I had to allow my phone to be **CWM**.

1. Download [CWM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3358005&d=1434021419).
2. Start [Odin](http://www.mediafire.com/download/b8w1on8pwd11yby/Odin+v3.09.zip).
3. Start the phone in Download mode by holding Volume Down, Home and Power. Plug the phone via USB to the PC.
4. In Odin, check AP and browse to CWM.tar file. Click Start.
5. Rebbot the phone (in my case it rebooted itself).

Now your phone can be CWM.

### SuperSU.zip

1. SuperSU.zip file can be downloaded [here](https://download.chainfire.eu/1021/SuperSU/SR3-SuperSU-v2.79-SR3-20170114223742.zip).
2. Store the file into a mini SD card, and plug the card in the phone.
3. Start your phone in CWM by holding Volume Up, Home and Power.
4. The the menu is clear and you can install the zip file.
5. Then browse in the menu to reboot the phone.

Now SuperSU works.

I also finally could remove crapy bloatware with Titanium Backup.

Comment: @Bebs That's quite a long edit you did there, could've been a standalone answer... I approved the edit at this moment, but if I have time later I will try to merge this to remove some irrelevant details and reduce clutter. For now, problem solved :) Let's delete the comments we left above.